# Is their any way to place content in IFRAME without using src

Tags: php, html, xml, iframe, editor

I have created a custom WYSIWYG editor for editing an XML file. I have used an `<iframe>` for this.
I have parsed the XML file and all the contents in a variable. How can I place this content in the `<iframe>`?
I tried this code but it is not working:

```
<iframe id="textbox"  style="width:300px; height:150px" >
     <?php echo $content ?>
</iframe>
```

Is their any javascript code for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to read the content from the XML file? If so, is the XML file on the server or the client? Do you want to load the content at page generation time or via AJAX?

Comment: I don't see the point of the code you put there... If you want to edit, iframe is useless I believe. Then, you shall read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to the [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), the content of an `<iframe>` is only displayed by browsers that don't support frames.
There's a simple solution though: Every other element *will* work for you. Consider using a simple `<div>`.

Comment: +1 `iframes` are outdated and will lead you directly to trouble, young man.

Comment: @Steve - Thanks! I wouldn't say they're outdated. They aren't too useful for pages in a single site, but they are excellent for sandboxing (think ads or widgets), and are still included in HTML 5: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: I have used this iframe for creating a custom wysiwyg editor.Is their any other way to create a wysiwyg editor

Comment: @THOmas - you *can* use an iframe, and set its `src` to a page of your choosing - for example, a dummy page that displays this xml. You can't place content directly in it though. They are quite a few editors, but I can't honestly recommend one.