# Is this possible to create iframe like this?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I want to create iframe like this. But I didint it.

```
   <iframe>
    <html>
     <style>/* codes */</style>
     <script type="javascript">/* codes */</script>
    </html>
    <body>
     Welcome!!
    </body>
    </iframe>
```

PHP codes :

```
function prew($html, $css, $js) {
    $iframe .= '<iframe>';    
    $iframe .= '<html>';
    $iframe .= '<head>';
    $iframe .= '<style>' . $css . '</style>';
    $iframe .= '<script>' . $js . '</script>';
    $iframe .= '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    $iframe .= '</head>';
    $iframe .= '<body>';
    $iframe .= $html;
    $iframe .= '</body>';
    $iframe .= '</html>';
    $iframe .= '</iframe>';
    return $iframe;
}
```

If I use this, it doesnt work. Why it is not working?
How can I create iframe as I want? I have searched more times but I could not find anything about this situation

Comment: Where is your calling part ? Define *not working* in brief.

Comment: `<iframe>` has an other purpose.. Just display your content in a DIV.

Comment: I can't see the `prev` function being called...

Comment: I am doing online editor. I should use iframe @A1rPun

Comment: @user3747708 Yes you can.. but you should use the `src` attribute on the iframe.

Comment: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133108/is-their-any-way-to-place-content-in-iframe-without-using-src) is related

Comment: if you want a dynamic content you gonna have to use javascript and put contents inside the iframe dynamically

Comment: I had already tried this. But I cant work js codes

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly echo an `<iframe>` with all the contents in it in PHP. They have to work side-by-side with javascript. In this example, i'l use jQuery.

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/c8eY2n)

```
<?php

// just the same as your code; construction of tags from PHP
function prew($html, $css, $js) {
    $iframe = '<html>';
    $iframe .= '<head>';
    $iframe .= '<style>' . $css . '</style>';
    $iframe .= '<script>' . $js . '</script>';
    $iframe .= '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
    $iframe .= '</head>';
    $iframe .= '<body>';
    $iframe .= $html;
    $iframe .= '</body>';
    $iframe .= '</html>';
    return $iframe;
}

// you client should request this
if(isset($_POST['get_contents'])) {
    // this is what you decide what you need to put inside, this is just a sample.
    echo prew('<div>hello world</div>', 'div{background-color: blue; width: 200px; color: white}', '');
    exit;
}

?>

<div class="contents"></div>
<button id="put_contents">Put contents</button>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#put_contents').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php', // the name of the php (in this case, same page)
            data: {get_contents: true},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(response) {
                // put the contents
                var $iframe = $('.contents').html('<iframe></iframe');
                $iframe.html(response);

            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```